# LED blinking eventhough we didnt code it to do that

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

This is our code:

```
void loop(
  for(int x=0; x<4; x++){ 
    Serial.println(x);
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    
  }
  for(int x=0; x<4; x++){
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(2000);
  }

  for(int x=0; x<4; x++){
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(1000);
 }
)
```

When we upload it it ignores most of the code and just starts blinking like when we connected it to the computer

Comment: I don't understand why you said the code didn't turn the led on or off when it obviously does. If your problem is that it's blinking *at a certain time* when it shouldn't, please update your question so that it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Huh your code is exactly doing what youre describing. It blinks.

```
for(int x=0; x<4; x++){ 
    Serial.println(x); -> idk if Serial.begin() was called 
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); -> turns led on
    delay(1000); -> waits 1s
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW); -> turns Led off
     delay(1000); -> waits 1s
}
```

If you want to wait for a Serial Connection before it Starts blinking you need to add

---

```
Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial) {
    //Do nothing - Some Arduino Models need this while loop
}
```

---

To your setup Function